# Is there any way to align float elements in center

Tags: html, css

[image]

You can see there is an extra space after fifth box. Is there any way to align it in center ?

Please note these boxes can be of any no.

Update:

Here is the jsfiddle link 
http://jsfiddle.net/esy2hgLm/

I'm trying to achieve the same using `display: flex` for dynamic width

Comment: I would suggest taking as look at `flexbox`. It makes centering a lot easier.

Comment: Even better, could you add a jsfiddle?

Comment: @LloanAlas i've added the link above

Comment: @FeaRCODE thanks will try and let you know

Comment: Do you want it like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/esy2hgLm/1/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto
}
```

Please note that this requires the wrapper to have a fixed width (which means it won't be ideal if the number of boxes changes).

I'd suggest taking a look at Flexbox for centering elements. Here's a couple of articles that you should read:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes
- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
- http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Note the lack of support for < IE9

Here's how that would look:

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;           
  flex-wrap: wrap;         
  justify-content: center; 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use some flexbox magic instead of floats:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;           /* Magic begins */
  flex-wrap: wrap;         /* Multiline */
  justify-content: center; /* Center items */
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: seagreen;
  margin: 20px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It bums me out that I had to expand that snippet. +1 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to align the wrapper, not the items. Make sure the wrapper is not wider than the content and add `margin: 0 auto;` to the wrapper CSS, which should center it in it's parent.

Comment: this will not work unless the wrapper has a fixed width

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `margin` of `0 auto`.

Try this:

```
.wrapper {
width: 600px;
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
}
```

Comment: is `display:block;` necessary here?

Comment: No it's not required, it can be excluded.